# Automatic autorestart Firefox on close

Tags: shell, firefox, script, sh

I want firefox to restart automatically when I close it. I found this script

```
#! /bin/sh

while [ true ]; do
        firefox
done
```

and I put a file with that script in the /etc/init.d folder. Firefox starts, but when I close it, it doesn't open again.

Comment: `/etc/init.d` is not the proper place for that script. See http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/ -- a script that automatically restarts firefox seems like it belongs in your personal `bin`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the test operator (`[`) around `true`:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    firefox
done
```

Comment: it doesn't work anyway. If I close firefox it doesn't open again. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Do you have any other windows of Firefox open? What happens if you add `echo Restarting` as the next line after `firefox`?

Comment: No. When I turn on the pc nothing is open, just the Firefox window. And I added the echo restarting line, but nothing happens.

Comment: Can't reproduce it here. What's your environment (OS, Firefox version)?

Comment: What happens when you run `firefox` from a command prompt and then close its window? Do you see a prompt again?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, Firefox 3.6.3.
If I run firefox in a terminal, the window appears and when I close it, I can use the terminal again, as usual

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31521/discussion-between-koterpillar-and-amk)

Comment: There's no problem using brackets around true. However, in that context, it's not the command `true`, but just a string. `[` when given one arguments returns success if the argument is non-empty.